# How to apply different free trials for different recurring items in the same order - Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

Let's say I have **2 items** in the order, and both items are **subscriptions**. I want to create a checkout session and give **free trial** for both **subscriptions**, but the **period** of free trial should be **different** for each subscription.

After checking [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create), I was able to set free trial to the whole order by specifying `subscription_data.trial_period_days` property on the order itself. But that will apply the same free trial to all subscriptions. I want to give a different free trial period to each subscription.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Hi there! It has to do with programming. Stripe checkout session is created programmatically in the backend, and you have to configure everything while creating it (items, prices, products, customers, free trials...). Stripe has one of the most powerful APIs in the world. If you closely read the question, I even added the link to the developer docs, and specified the config that I found.

Comment: It does have a powerful API, but even your answer lacks any programming information. This question is a support question for the API, not a programming question.

Comment: Well, you can say that now. But before I got their answer, I though that it could be done with some different configuration. The same as `null` value is still a valid value, the answer `It can not be done` is still valid answer. The question/answer does not have to have code included to be considered "programming" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Stripe Support and they told me that session can be either one-time payment or subscription. If it's a subscription, it can have only one free trial period specified, and that free trial period would apply to all recurring items in the session.

> Subscriptions can only have one billing cycle. If you're creating one
> session with multiple pricing, this won't create a separate
> subscription but one single subscription. So you can't just assign a
> trial to a specific pricing as this would cause a different billing
> cycle anchor.

Answer (score 1):

The `trial_peroid_days` is a property you specify when creating a Subscription object, and it would apply to all line items in the subscription.

If you want to apply a different trial period for an item, you can create another subscription for that particular item with a different trial period.

Comment: As I said, I am using checkout session where I have to specify all items in the order. I know I can split order items to multiple orders with one subscription, but that is not a good UX for a user. I want the user to purchase all items that he wants with one order.